# Sqlite Conversion

Tags: sqlite

How do I convert the query below to sqlite?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
unite.UniteAd+'('+IIf(IsNull(Left(Semt.Semt,50)),'',Left(Semt.Semt,50))+')' 
AS UniteAd
```

I tried to use case...when instead of iif but I keep getting error.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to replace IIF and ISNULL with CASE and to replace LEFT with SUBSTR.  Also, you need to use || to concatenate, instead of +.

If you've made those changes and it still doesn't work, please post the resulting SQL that is failing.  I'd try it for you, but I can't figure out what you mean by:

```
IIf(IsNull(Left(Semt.Semt,50)),'',Left(Semt.Semt,50))
```

Comment: I think this is right SELECT DISTINCT unite.UniteAd + '('+ CASE WHEN SUBSTR(Semt.Semt,0,50) is null THEN '' ELSE SUBSTR(Semt.Semt,0,50) +')' as UniteAd

Comment: What is the purpose of `SUBSTR(Semt.Semt,0,50)`?  Are you trying to evaluate whether Semt.Semt is NULL?

Comment: I am trying to get first 50 characters of the column which is called Semt. Here I am using SUBSTR instead of LEFT function.